# How many integer solutions of $217x^3+8x^2+15x+15=0 \pmod {77}$?

Tags: number-theory

> How many integer solutions of $217x^3+8x^2+15x+15=0 \pmod {77}$?

This is my question. I have already done $f(2^8) = 0 \pmod {7}$, but I can't solve this thing.

Comment: Might be easier to work mod $7$ and $11$ separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial modulo $7$ becomes
$$
x^2+x+1=x^2-6x+8=(x-2)(x-4)
$$

Modulo $11$ the polynomial becomes
$$
8x^3+8x^2+4x+4=4(x+1)(2x^2+1)=8(x+1)(x^2+6)=8(x-10)(x-4)(x-7)
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Oh thanks I've already done it!! But thanks alot to answer my question ~~